# Windows Azure: Outbound request from hosted application

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a `Windows Azure` app that needs to make an outbound request to another third party SQL Server.
The third party doesn't want to allow just any connection to their database from any source so they would like to restrict connections to subset of IP Addresses or a given subdomain.
I know when you login to the `Windows Azure management portal` that it lists the IP addresses for a given instance of our app but we presume these can change without notice and if were to use these and they changed we would be up a creek.
Do outbound requests from a Windows Azure app come from the `appname.cloudapp.net` domain? 
Is it safe to assume that all outbound requests will be identified as coming from that domain and to use that for connection restrictions on the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't delete your deployment your virtual IP will stay the same. Outbound requests from any of the cloud service instances will appear from the deployment's virtual IP.

From MSDN:

> The VIP doesn’t change unless you delete the deployment explicitly or
>   it is implicitly deleted by the deployment update process. To retain
>   the VIP, you must not delete your deployment, and you must also make
>   sure that Visual Studio doesn’t delete your deployment automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/jj614593.aspx

Comment: Do you know if an outbound request will be identified by out cloudapp.net domain name as well?  Meaning will the referring domain be appname.cloudapp.net?

Comment: You should have control of this behaviour, for example if it's an outbound HTTP request you can add the `Referrer` header with whatever name you like. Azure doesn't support reverse DNS so you can't get the `cloudapp.net` host name from the deployment IP.